# Localizing for both Simplified and Traditional Chinese in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, localization

Xcode 4 defaults to naming both languages as "Chinese" in the project navigator, making it super confusing when I need to edit localizations. Is there a way to make it show Traditional/Simplified Chinese, or even zh-Hans/zh-Hant instead of just "Chinese"?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What version of Xcode are you using? In Xcode 4.5.2 I am seeing the following:

[image]

Even with this extended description, you are still not out of the woods. If you add zh-Hant-HK and zh-Hans-HK

[image]

you get the same description for both in the languages menu:

[image]

Time for a bug report to the Xcode team.

Comment: The problem is that I'm specifically localizing for zh-Hans and zh-Hant, which are both described as "Chinese". I'm not localizing for the other Chinese "dialects".